# Avoid creation of db-WAL db-shm files in sqlite databases

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using **python** module **sqlite3** to read data stored in .db files

I realized that event though I read the files in read only mode and the connection is properly closed, both .db-wal and db-shm remain in the server

As the data is stored in db files every 10min It can create a bunch of files in the server

I read a bit about WAL methods and PRAGMA but I could not get a clear explanation about how to avoid their creation or make sure that they are deleted once the connection is closed. Trying to delete them manually it is not an option as they are stored in a server in which I do not have write access

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not want to do anything with these files. Secondly, one of this files is created **per database**. If this file is left after a connection is closed, no new file will be created on your next connection, but the existing file will be used. Do not mess with database's normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable WAL mode for the SQLite database itself (it's a property of the database, not the connection) with something like:

```
$ sqlite3 data/ratelimits.db
SQLite version 3.43.0 2023-08-24 12:36:59
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> pragma journal_mode;
delete
sqlite> pragma journal_mode=wal;
wal
sqlite>
```

In your case, you it sounds like you want to disable WAL, so I think you want to set `pragma journal_mode=delete` instead.

Note that you should avoid deleting these files yourself, since the write-ahead log (.db-wal) can contain information about recent transactions. It should be deleted automatically as SQLite works, or when you disable WAL.